# finding wxpython event documentation

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How can I find out the functions and attributes of the various events released by wxpython?

When a bound function is triggered an event is sent to the bound function e.g.:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.eventButtonFunction, self.button)
...
def eventButtonFunction(self,event):
```

Each widget (e.g. checkbox, togglebutton etc) has a different set of attributes and functions. I can't find this information in the docs and so have been resorting to using dir to print them all out like so:

```
def eventButtonFunction(self,event):
    for s in dir(event):
        print s
```

Which is very annoying. Is this in the docs somewhere which I am missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wxPython docs aren't as complete as the underlying C++ wxWidgets docs, so in many cases, you'll have to use the C++ docs, generally translating all symbols of the form `wxFoo` to `wx.Foo`.

You're probably looking for something like [this list](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_eventhandlingoverview.html#eventmacros), which is a list of all the event classes mapped to the macros to which they apply, and each class is hyperlinked to the class definition, although it's still not entirely complete.

From memory, `EVT_BUTTON` generates a [`wxCommandEvent`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxcommandevent.html#wxcommandevent), although if you're not sure which event type you're getting, printing a `repr` of the event object should help.

For example...

```
def eventButtonFunction(self, event):
    print repr(event)
```

...yields...

```
<wx._core.CommandEvent; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxCommandEvent *' at 0x21eaec> >
```

It's a bit of a pain at first, but after you've used wxPython for a while, you'll get used to it.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't say wxCommandEvent anywhere on the wxWidgets or wxpython doc pages for wxButton. So can I ask how you worked out that it generated a wxCommandEvent?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to these docs, which are admittedly, confusing:

http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html

All the events are derived from that event. So you'll have to click on a sub-class to see what other methods are added. And some of those sub-classes have additional sub-classes and methods. Yes, it's kind of ugly.